# Language used to built smart contracts in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger, ethereum, hyperledger-composer, solidity, smartcontracts

As Solidity is used to create Smart Contracts in Ethereum, Which language is used to create a smart contract in Hyperledger Composer?

Comment: The example provided [here](https://developer.ibm.com/code/patterns/create-and-execute-blockchain-smart-contracts/) (behind the "get the code" button) is written in Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For business networks, ecmascript (commonly referred to as javascript) is the language supported by composer. It supports ecmascript 6 and also includes support for async/await. Node v8 is used as the runtime.

For client side there is a client SDK again for ecmascript, but also a rest server and so you can develop client applications in whatever language you prefer when interacting with the composer rest server.